# Delay and then auto close DIV

Tags: jquery, overlay

(excused for my english, I'm dutch)

I'm creating an overlay with multiple effects and clicks. To setup the overlay and the general effects (slide, fade, duration,...) there's no problem. As for some actions there's need an automated close after a few seconds.

Here is my jQuery code for the total animation.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // START DOCUMENT READY

    // Start welkombox overlay
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#welkombox div[rel]").overlay();
    });
    // End welkombox overlay

    // Start slide overlay content
    jQuery('#verhuiskeuze1-wachten').click(function() {
        jQuery('#verhuis-algemeen, #verhuis-wachten').animate(
            { left: "+=100%" }, // what we are animating
            {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'easeOutQuad',
            }
        );
    });
    // End slide overlay content

    // END DOCUMENT READY
});
```

Here is a simple version of the body.

```
<!-- Visable content on page -->
<div id="content-inner">
    <div id="welkombox">
        <div id="box1" rel="#related1">Some content...</div>
        <div id="box2" rel="#related2">Some content...</div>
        <div id="box3" rel="#related3">Some content...</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Overlay content, witch s visible onclick of one of the boxes above -->
<div id="related1" class="overlay">
    <div id="Inside-part1">Some text (button to slide, defind in the Jquery script)</div>
    <div id="Inside-part2">Some text</div>
</div>

<div id="related2" class="overlay">Some content...</div>
<div id="related3" class="overlay">Some content...</div>
```

Now for what I want exactly to do:

1. Create overlay if clicked on div in the body content. (DONE)
2. Open the refering overlay of witch div container was clicked. (DONE)
3. In my project there are 2 div's (as clickable items) with actions. For one of them the content with in the overlay moves to the right side and showes some other content. (DONE)
4. If that last is done (click and move tot right) the overlay is suposed to close automaticly after a few seconds.

The last thing is something what seems to be impossible.
Is there someone how can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `.animate()` but you don't specify the complete function that will be called after animation has finished. That is the point when you have to set a timeout for your *overlay* to be closed.

This is how it's done:

```
// all code that you already have...

.animate({ left: "+=100%" }, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeOutQuad',
    complete: function() {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $("selector").hide(); // or .remove()
        }, 1000); // adjust time
    }
});
```

### Additional observations

This code seems unnecessary:

```
// Start welkombox overlay
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#welkombox div[rel]").overlay();
});
// End welkombox overlay
```

Instead you should just call:

```
// Start welkombox overlay
jQuery("#welkombox div[rel]").overlay();
// End welkombox overlay
```

Because you're already in the ready event handler. No need to add another handler. And these two are equivalent (because I've seen you use two of them):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { /* document read code */ });
// is the same as this shorter version
jQuery(function() { /* document read code */ });
```

### Trailing commas

Beware of trailing commas in your objects. Example:

```
...
{
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutQuad", // <-- remove this comma
}
...
```

This will make the object invalid in IE and won't be created at all. IE is very sensitive about this. Other browsers still work though...